# Redirect after delete post in Frontend

Tags: front-end

I use the following link to delete a post in the frontend of wordpress:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ) ?>">Delete Post</a>
```

This works fine. But after i delete the post its just showing a blank page of the index.php. I want to redirect the author who deletetd the post to a category site like /post-archive. Any idea how i can do that?

Thx for your help and best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a little bit more into this topic and found this solution which works perfect for me.

1 Add this code to functions.php:

```
// Delete post
function delete_post(){
    global $post;
    $deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true', get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ) );
    if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) {
        echo       '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return confirm(\'¿Are you sure to delete?\')" href="'.$deletepostlink.'">Borrar</a></span>';
    }
}

//Redirect after delete post in frontend
add_action('trashed_post','trash_redirection_frontend');
function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id) {
    if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl').'/page-deleted-post' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

2 Call the function on youre template file (single.php or whatever):

```
echo delete_post();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach by modifying the *redirect location* after the post has been *trashed*:

```
/**
 * Redirect to the home url after trashing a post on the front-end
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212146/26350
 */
add_action( 'trashed_post', function()
{
    add_filter( 'wp_redirect', function( $location, $status )
    {
        if (   is_wpse_part_of_admin_url( $location ) 
            && 1 == get_wpse_query_arg( $location, 'trashed' )
        )
            $location = esc_url( home_url() ); // Adjust to your needs!

        return $location;
    } );
} );
```

Note: we make sure that the redirect location is not within the backend with the help of our `is_wpse_part_of_admin_url()` helper function.

There are handy functions like `add_query_arg()` and `remove_query_arg()` but not `get_query_arg()`. So here's our helper function:

```
/**
 * Get query argument from an url
 *
 * @uses wp_parse_str()
 * @param string $url 
 * @param string $arg
 * @return string|false
 */
function get_wpse_query_arg( $url, $arg )
{
    wp_parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $args );

    if( isset( $args[$arg] ) )
        return $args[$arg];

    return false;
}
```

Here's our helper function to determine if the url is a backend url:

```
/**
 * Check if the url starts with admin_url()
 *
 * @uses admin_url()
 * @param string $url 
 * @return boolean
 */
function is_wpse_part_of_admin_url( $url )
{
    return 0 === strpos( $url, admin_url() );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this still works.  I get:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 1 passed in class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 2 expected

For this line:
add_filter( 'wp_redirect', function( $location, $status )